# Distance (pixels) from an <img> to the bottom of the containing div

Tags: javascript

I have a div which contains a few images. The images are styled to appear in a vertical column:

```
.side_gallery img {
    display: block;
    margin: 3px 5px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

I have a javascript function which loops over these images and tweaks them. I want a simple way to calculate the distance, in pixels, from the bottom of each image to the bottom of the containing `<div>`.

Comment: Did you find an answer? If so please accept one. If not, let us know what went wrong so we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need to get the height of the div (`yourDiv.offsetHeight`), the location of your image (`yourImage.offsetTop`), the height of your image (`yourImage.offsetHeight`) and then apply a tiny bit of math.

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
var bottom = (div.offsetHeight) - (img.offsetTop + img.offsetHeight);
```

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/vhuwS/)

I hope this has helped.

Comment: Oh wait, offsetTop uses the top of the page, let me just fix that!

Comment: Okay, fixed it. Just had to add the div's offset height.

Comment: I think this'll do it. I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: `offsetTop` is from the parent element, not the top of the page, so `var bottom = (div.offsetHeight) - (img.offsetTop + img.offsetHeight);` worked. Modify the answer to that and I'll accept it.

Comment: I see, well I have changed it. I hope you have your problem sorted now!

Comment: Everything's working grand now, thanks. I may put a demo up somewhere to show what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of each image in pixels and its position in the div then you can do the math, then you can do the math:

If the position of the image is its top left corner, then:
Distance = DivSize - imageSize - imagePosition;

If the position of the image is its bottom left corner, then:
Distance = DivSize - imagePosition

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use jQuery for those things because of differences between browsers

```
// this line launches our js after the page is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// this line search for the images in the div with id = "content"
  jQuery("#content >img").each(function(index) {

  //  caching img for saving time
           var img =jQuery(this);
  //get image height
           var img_height = img.height()
  //get image distance from parent top 
           var img_parent_top_distance = img.offset().top;
    // get parent height
           var parent_height=img.parent().height()
    // do what you need width bottom distance (parent_height - img_parent_top_distance -img_height)
           alert("img_height:"+img_height
                  +"\n img_parent_top_distance:"+img_parent_top_distance
                  +"\n parent_height:"+parent_height 
                  +"\n bottom distance"+  (parent_height - img_parent_top_distance -img_height) )
    });
```

});

works with this HTML

```
<h1>hola</h1>
<div style="height:600px ;background-color: grey;" id="content">
<img src="gato1.jpg" id="1">
<img src="gato2.jpg" id="2">
<img src="gato3.jpg" id="3">
<img src="gato4.jpg" id="4">
<img src="gato1.jpg" id="1">
<img src="gato2.jpg" id="2">
<img src="gato3.jpg" id="3">
<img src="gato4.jpg" id="4">
</div>
```